# Setting reminder due date takes too long in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, command-line, reminders

Maybe someone can explain why is that like this and how to speed things up

```bash
# this is for some reason is pretty slow and takes >=11s to execute
osascript << EOF
    tell app "Reminders"
        set rem to make new reminder in default list with properties {name:"$name", body:"$link"}
        set allday due date of rem to (current date) # without this script executes almost immediately
    end tell
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(current date)` command is not a **Reminders.app** command.  It's a **Standard Additions** command.

Try this...

```
osascript << EOF
set theDate to (current date)
tell application "Reminders"
    set rem to make new reminder in default list with properties {name:"$name", body:"$link"}
    set allday due date of rem to theDate
end tell
EOF
```

Comment: that doesn't help, I get the same results :c

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments in your script here.

```
osascript << EOF
    set todayDate to (current date)
    tell application "Reminders"
        set listName to list "List Name"
        tell listName
            make new reminder at end with properties {name:"$name", body:"$link", allday due date:allday of todayDate}
        end tell
    end tell
EOF
```

1. As mentioned in the other answer, it's better to add `(current date)` to a variable.
2. You have to set a list in which the reminder will be added and tell the list (not Reminders directly) to add the reminder.
3. No need to make a variable if you can have it in a single line.
4. `allday due date` could be a parameter of the new reminder properties.

<sub>*Thanks to [this](https://gist.github.com/n8henrie/c3a5bf270b8200e33591) repository for the essential parts*</sub>